# Pandas 'to_json' function returning wrong format of date

Tags: python, pandas, date-format, to-json

I am still facing a problem in receiving correct date formatted data from the CSV using to_json fu
nction of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shubham\\Desktop\\Output\\MasterData.csv")
df1 = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(df1)

[{"invoiceDate":"18\/08\/2019","amount":1140.87}]
```

I am expecting Output:- "invoiceDate":"18/08/2019"

I already tried to_json arguments:-  date_format = "iso" double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None), and replace is also not working (df.replace("/","")).

Comment: Please share your df (no need for a csv), or more correctly, a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: May I know Why do you want to remove `backslash`. In json `"promotionValidFrom":"10\/12\/2019"` and `"promotionValidFrom":"10/12/2019"` is same. backslash(escape character) is for precaution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this date format issue by replace function.
Later I got to python only add on additional backward slash if our data type is date, not string.

```py
df1 = df.to_json(orient='records',lines=True).replace('\\r\\n', " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def OCRExecution():
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shubham\\OS_task\\masterData.csv")
    df1 = df.to_json(orient='records')
    df1.replace("\","")
    return df1
OCRExecution()
```